# Gradle buildSrc breaking with Koltin scripting host dependency

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying to add a code generation bit to my project, so I went ahead and made `buildSrc`, made a tiny build script, and a minimal task class. However, when I sync the build with Intellij, it fails with `COMPILE_INCREMENTAL_WITH_ARTIFACT_TRANSFORM`. That's it, nothing more. No other error information. Strangely enough, if I remove the `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-jvm-host` dependency, it compiles fine. What might be causing this?

buildSrc/build.gradle.kts

```kotlin
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-common")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-jvm")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-jvm-host") // This is causing the issue
}
```

buildSrc/main/kotlin/io/github/seggan/rol/astgen/AstGenTask.kt

```kotlin
package io.github.seggan.rol.astgen

import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask

abstract class AstGenTask : DefaultTask() {
}
```

I have tried cleaning the build, no effect. I originally had more code in the task, tried removing that, still no effect.

Answer (score 0):

[Following this official guide](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/custom-script-deps-tutorial.html#create-a-script-definition) seems like you missed a dependency which is:

`implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4")`

Based on the guide provided by Kotlin team, this dependency is mandatory in this case. Try adding it and following the guide closely.